# Using python need to get the substrings

Tags: python-3.x

Q)After executing the code Need to print the values [1, 12, 123, 2, 23, 3, 13], but iam getting [1, 12, 123, 2, 23, 3]. I have missing the letter 13. can any one tell me the reason to overcome that error?

```
def get_all_substrings(string):       
  length = len(string)   
  list = []  
  for i in range(length):   
    for j in range(i,length):  
       list.append(string[i:j+1])   
  return list  
values = get_all_substrings('123')  
results = list(map(int, values))   
print(results)      
count = 0   
for i in results:  
   if i > 1 :    
      if (i % 2) != 0:     
          count += 1    
print(count)
```

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward issue in your nested `for` loops within `get_all_substrings()`, lets walk it!

You are iterating over each element of your string `123`:

`for i in range(length) # we know length to be 3, so range is 0, 1, 2`

You then iterate each subsequent element from the current `i`:

`for j in range(i,length)`

Finally you append a string from position `i` to `j+1` using the slice operator:

`list.append(string[i:j+1])`

But what exactly is happening? Well we can step through further!

The first value of `i` is `0`, so lets skip the first `for`, go to the second:

```
for j in range(0, 3): # i.e. the whole string!
    # you would eventually execute all of the following
    list.append(string[0:0 + 1]) # '1'
    list.append(string[0:1 + 1]) # '12'
    list.append(string[0:2 + 1]) # '123'
    # but wait...were is '13'???? (this is your hint!)
```

The next value of `i` is 1:

```
for j in range(1, 3):
    # you would eventually execute all of the following
    list.append(string[1:1 + 1]) # '2'
    list.append(string[1:2 + 1]) # '23'
    # notice how we are only grabbing values of position i or more?
```

Finally you get to `i` is `2`:

```
for j in range(2, 3): # i.e. the whole string!
    # you would eventually execute all of the following
    list.append(string[2:2 + 1]) # '3'
```

I've shown you what is happening (as you've asked in your question), I leave it to you to devise your own solution. A couple notes:

- You need to look at all index combinations from position `i`
- Dont name objects by their type (i.e. dont name a `list` object `list`)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this using itertools and powerset() recipe

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s) + 1))

output = list(map(''.join, powerset('123')))
output.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, using combinations

```
from itertools import combinations


def get_sub_ints(raw):
    return [''.join(sub) for i in range(1, len(raw) + 1) for sub in combinations(raw, i)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_sub_ints('123'))

>>> ['1', '2', '3', '12', '13', '23', '123']
```